# Unable to run Zip 2 Secure EXE (Free) Version 14.5.0

Tags: chilkat, sfx

I am using free version of Zip 2 Secure EXE and I keep getting the following error.  I had done this 2 years ago without an issue. Also the Version created by is stamped as 15.0.0. Is the current download for 14.5.0 or 15.0.0? Can I get older version of the Zip 2 Exe which was working?

I have very old version of Zip 2 Secure EXE which doesn't launch setup.exe if I allow user to select custom folder.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

Found working version here
http://zip-2-secure-exe.software.informer.com/download/

looks like latest version is buggy for larger sizes.